# Finding the anti Gradient?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have this question that says $f(x,y,z)$ such that $\nabla f(x,y,z) = <2xy,2yz+x^2,y^2>$

The way I see this is that they are asking for what can you take the partial derivative of with respect $x y$ and $z$ so that you get that $\nabla f(x,y,z)$

My answer would be $f(x,y,z) = (x^2y+y^2z+x^2y,y^2z) $

Comment: What is an anti gradient?

Comment: Honestly I just used that term vaguely I am thinking they are asking me to find something that will become the ∇f(x,y,z)

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is called the potential function. We have: $\nabla f = (f_x,f_y,f_z)$. Thus $f_x = 2xy\implies f = \int 2xydx + g(y,z)= x^2y+ g(y,z)\implies f_y = x^2 + \dfrac{\partial g(y,z)}{\partial y}=2yz + x^2\implies g(y,z) = \int 2yzdy + h(z)= y^2z + h(z)\implies f_z = y^2 + h'(z) = y^2\implies h'(z) = 0 \implies h(z) = C\implies f(x,y,z) = x^2y + y^2z + C$ ( constant ).

Comment: Could you explain a little bit in words how the process goes I am confused about why the g(y,z) came from. Just a little insight on your steps.

Comment: when you deal with partial derivative with respect to a variable, other variables regarded as constants, thus the $g(y,z)$ is thought of as a constant when you integrate with respect to the variable $x$ since the function is not a single variable any more, its a 3-variable function.

Comment: For this line 2yz+x2⟹g(y,z)=∫2yzdy+h(z)=y2z+h(z) where does the x^2 go?

Comment: You can apply this type of algorithm for any desired $\mathbf{F}=(f_x,f_y,f_z)$ but it will not give you the desired result unless $\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = 0$.

Comment: @DeepSea or others,  interesting! Which branch of math, physics, etc, introduces this concept of potential functions? Any good references to introduce about potential functions? The term is so overloaded that I was not able to directly find it in the same context.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a sort of algorithm for myself in taking the "anti-gradient" and it personally expedites the process for me.

For a vector valued function,

**F** = grad(f) = (H,G,I)

You start by sorting all of the linearly independent terms (LITs) in **F** into three categories (or subsets) *p, q & r* for each H,G and I.

That is,

{H}={p,q,r} ,{G}={p,q,r}, {I}={p,q,r}

***p*-terms**:

- All LITs that themselves depend on the 2 variables that were not
  apart of the partial differentiation (independent variables).

*For the component H, p-terms would have to be a function of (y,z) as the partial derivative was with respect to x.*

***q*-terms**:

- All LITs that depend on at least 2 variables in which one must be the dependent variable.

or

- All LITs that depend on only one of the independent variables.

*For H, q-terms would include functions of: (x,y), (x,z), (x,y,z), (z) or (y)
Basically q is anything that's not p or r.*

***r*-terms**:

- All LITs that depend only on the dependent variable.

*For H, r-terms are functions of x.*

Once you have these sorted out you simply plug them into the following formula.

***∫*** (Hp+Hq+Hr)**dx** + (Gq+Gr)**dy** + (Ir)**dz**

in essence,

*f = C1(x,y,z) + C2(y,z) + C3(z) + C4*

As an aside, I found this particularly useful when calculating f for an irrotational vector field in a line integral. It saved me a ton of time on tests.

Comment: Interesting. Ever thought of something that generalizes to N dimensions?